# How to implement KVO on UIStepper

Tags: iphone, ios, key-value-observing, uistepper

i am creating small demo of `KVO`. As per my knowledge `KVO` use to notify when property value is changes. I want to implement `KVO` on `UIStepper`. I want to notify when user change value of `UIStepper`. I did some code on that as follows.

`ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper;
}

@property NSInteger intToObserve;

@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize intToObserve;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    stepper.minimumValue = 0;
    stepper.maximumValue = 1000;
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"intToObserve" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    double value = [sender value];
    intToObserve = value;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"Notification Received");
}
@end
```

Problem is that when i hit plus button stepper value is changed but my notification method did not received any notification or even i set break point there but control not goes there. means `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath` not called.

Please suggest some idea, what i am doing wrong or to work this what is another solution ??

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it via the setter method or the notification will not fire.  Change

```
intToObserve = value;
```

to

```
self.intToObserve = value;
```

Comment: One more thing to ask. How do i get new changed value in notification method. Can i get new stepper value in integer ??

Comment: All that info is in the change dictionary.  See the docs for more info.